# Laravel 5.3 Returns 302 with Request Validation - Ajax Request

Tags: ajax, superagent, laravel-5.3

I am having trouble with an ajax request to a Laravel application, specifically making a POST request to an authentication controller. I'm sending a post request with SuperAgent to a controller that uses a Request class to validate the input. The request carries a password and a username. When I inspect the console I'm getting back a `GET 200 OK` and a `POST 302 Not Found`. I tried debugging the application routes but nothing seemed to work.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out it was something very simple. Having used jquery for a long time to make ajax request, I overlooked a very important header. The `'Accept', 'application/json'` Header. Debugging the Request validation, I noticed that Laravel's `expectsJson` method was returning false, so all I had to do was add said header to the SuperAgent request object.